# Error : DocumentApp is not defined in google docs

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am constantly getting this error "DocumentApp is not defined". I am working with google drive using drive api. When i am trying to fetch current opened google doc using

`DocumentApp.openById('My-file-Id');`

but I am constantly getting this error "**documentApp is not defined**". Please help me to fix it out or show me the right way to do this.

```
function printFile(fileId) 
{
    $("#demo_scope").collapse('show');

    var response_data = '<span class="custome_span_text"><center><img src="<?php echo base_url("img/loading.gif");?> "> Wait open the document ...</center></span>';

    $("#google_drive_iframe").show();
    $("#google_drive_iframe").html(response_data);

    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
       'fileId': fileId
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) 
    {
        if(resp.code != 404)
        {
            file = resp;
            var file_id = file.id;

            var some_magic = DocumentApp.openById('My-file-Id');    <!-- Here i am getting error -->

            var file_title = file.title; 
            var file_modifiedDate =  new Date(file.modifiedDate);
            var exportLinks = file.exportLinks;
            var exportLink_html = exportLinks["text/html"];
            $("#google_doc_filenm").val(file_title);
            $("#doc_file_id").val(file_id);
            $("#google_drive_iframe").show(); 
            $("#google_drive_iframe").html('<iframe  src="'+file.alternateLink+'" onclick="checkFocus();"  class="google_iframe"></iframe>');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#google_drive_iframe").html("<center><span class='error_title'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Google Document has been not available !</span></center>");
            alertify.error("Please select google document");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) in order to understand how to ask on SO. Show us more from that what you have done so far and post your code.

Comment: @Peter, Thanks for your comment, basically i am creating a web-application in which i want to integrate google docs using google drive. I have made it. Now my next task it append some data to that opened google doc using drive API. So i want cursor position for that. But i don't know how to find out cursor position using drive API? I searched lot on a google and found solution that i can do that using google APP Script. but i am getting above error. I think now you can understand.

Comment: I understand that you have a problem, but there is no chance how one can say more about your problem than your error message already tells you. `documentApp is not defined`, means: This object is not defined in that scope. If you don't provide more information, nobody will be able to help you. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: @peter I have updated the code. Please check it.

Comment: Hi @ChintanPanchal, were you able to resolve this issue? (PS: I'm looking for solution too.)